# Including health advice in the personal medical questions off-topic reason

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The current custom off-topic close reason for medical advice is the following

> Personal medical questions are off-topic on Biology. We can not safely
>   answer questions for your specific situation and you should always
>   consult a doctor for medical advice.

I propose to change it to include health advice:

> Personal medical questions and health advice are off-topic on Biology. We can not safely
>   answer questions for your specific situation and you should always
>   consult a doctor for medical advice.

As [discussed in this previous meta post](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/policy-on-health-questions), I think health questions are not a good fit for the site and should be closed. This concerns mostly questions like "Is X healthy?" that are not about understanding biological mechanisms.

If there are no objections, I'll change the close reason to my proposed new wording. I'm open to any suggestions on a better wording, or any other feedback on the issue.

Comment: +1 I think this is a good idea.

Comment: +1 seconded, and still of the opinion that the previous featured question and now the current featured question were too close to health advice for my comfort.

Comment: Looks good to me. Go for it!

Comment: I also agree with the change. @AtlLED, which Qs are you referring to?

Comment: [this one](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21632/why-do-different-pain-killers-have-different-effects-on-people/) and [this one](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21934/what-are-the-psychodelic-effects-of-stellar-anise-and-how-many-people-are-affe)

Comment: It looks like there will soon be [a place to re-route these](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health).

Comment: @Susan This place WILL lead to legal issues, I'm afraid...

Comment: @Raoul I've had similar concerns....

Comment: I rolled back my edit since I saw that you have already implemented it with that wording. Could you change _can not_ to _cannot_? The latter is used [almost exclusively](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/4516/25030) in modern English.

Comment: [Skeptics](https://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/close-reason-for-medical-advice-questions) may use a version of this as a close reason. Is that okay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now done, health advice is added to the personal medical questions close reason.

Comment: I'd like to add that there is a possibility for some apparent health questions to be in scope for [**Physical Fitness** beta](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/). They take some nutrition/health questions.

Comment: The clarification on health advice should be added to [the help pages as well](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (currently only "*personal medical questions*" are mentioned there). This is what new users (hopefully) read for guidance, not the close-reason texts.

Comment: @fileunderwater done