# What is "Health Advice"?

Tags: discussion

In [this post](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/706/) and [this post](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/), Health Advice as a close-reason was discussed:

> As discussed in this previous meta post, I think health questions are not a good fit for the site and should be closed. **This concerns mostly questions like "Is X healthy?" that are not about understanding biological mechanisms**.

Does this question fall into this? [Survival of streptococcus after my scarlet fever](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/29996/survival-of-streptococcus-after-my-scarlet-fever/30007#30007)

This seems to be a perfectly valid bacteriology question dealing with probabilty of infection and prevention.

Please explain explicitly what is meant by health advice?

"Will a specific strategy prevent something?" type of question is asking about biological mechanisms and this is explicitly not about treatment. As these deal specifically with epidemiology are these questions not welcome here?

Comment: *But my question is, what about the streptococci I've spread before?* *"...does that mean, I have to disinfect the whole house? And if so, with what should I desinfect? I worked heavily on the laptop, how do I desinfect that?"* may very well be construed as asking for medical advice. If the question were more general, and without reference to his own illness, it might make a reasonable epidemiology question.

Comment: Any question that sounds like "*What should I do to ...*" can be considered a health advice. Though this OP may just be curious about a situation but there are people who may eventually blame the site when that advice did not work out for them. We are not responsible for anyone's health. The question should be asked in a general tone and as mentioned by @anongoodnurse, any reference to a personal situation should be removed.